# NGINX return 404 error when adding a trailing slash

Tags: laravel, nginx, plesk

Today, I have a problem with NGINX.

In my NGINX config I have this :

```
location ~ / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

For example, I want to access https://my.domain/hello with a route defined with Laravel. It works
but now if I access https://my.domain/hello/ it returns a 404 NGINX error page. I also point out that I use Plesk.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix that ?

Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: Same issue it seems to be a problem with plesk only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 301 redirect if path is not directory and ending on `/`

```
if (!-d $request_filename) {
   rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the nginx config template you will find this line

`/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php`

```
        <?php if ($VAR->domain->physicalHosting->directoryIndex && !$VAR->domain->physicalHosting->proxySettings['nginxProxyMode']): ?>
     location ~ /$ {
         index <?=$VAR->quote($VAR->domain->physicalHosting->directoryIndex)?>;
     }
         <?php endif ?>
```

You either need to reenable proxy mode (it will reenable apache but nginx will still be receiving the request in the first place) or [create a custom template](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/advanced-administration-guide-linux/virtual-hosts-configuration/changing-virtual-hosts-settings-using-configuration-templates.68693/) for your domain and delete this line

This will not concern you, but if you were not using php (eg: nodejs), you could also disable php support, which would also get rid of this line